# Java Filenotfound exception in jar file

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

i wrote a program, but when my friends try to execute it it throw filenotfound exception, but the file is exist, here is my code, and in the folder have  lib folder, the jar file and the "csv fajlok" and in the csv fajlok folder there is the 2 csv file

```
String csvFile = "csv fajlok\\pontcsoport.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";

    try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] pontGroupLine = line.split(";");
        String[] price_split = pontGroupLine[1].split(" ");

            try{
               doubleDTList.add(Double.parseDouble(price_split[0]));
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
             }                   
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nem található a pontcsoport fájl (/csv fajlok)");
    }catch (IOException e) {
    }finally {
        if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to verify this path"csv fajlok\\pontcsoport.csv"

Comment: Try to verify you current working directory: `System.out.println("Current working dir: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: Try debugging with a breakpoint, it would be good to know the exception message as well as where does it break

Answer (score 2):

If the file is outside the jar file, you should put an absolute path, or the "csv fajlok" folder should be in the same folder where you execute the jar file.

If the file is inside the jar file, you cannot access to it as a file but as a Stream, with the method `Class.getResourceAsStream(String path)`.

Comment: the "csv fajlok" folder is in the same folder with the jar, that's why i dont know why is it throw exception, i tried on 4 notebook, on 2 notebook its working and the other 2 is not

Answer (score 1):

Better to use Java NIO2 to read the file content:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path-to-file"), charset);
```

It's allow to avoid using while loop with redundant readers.

What is the OS installed on failed notebooks?

Also try to change folder name using '_' instead of space. I think it's the main reason of the issue.

Comment: On 3 notebook have w8.1 and 1 win7, on my win8.1 and w7 its working fine, but the other win8.1 its throw exception, i tried to write the folder name csv_fajlok but it didnt help